# How to capture OTP code from gmail email content by using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit4

I have tried to copy a gmail content (OTP) code.

But the selenium webdriver is unable to locate the `xpath/id/title/gettext/` for that particular gmail (email) content.
The code is given below

Please refer the screen shot for the code.

Please help to copy the email content.

Comment: There is no screen shot given and no code....

Comment: Please provide code and HTML source